# Material UI - DataGrid custom list filter

Tags: javascript, filter, material-ui

I tried some custom filters on the Material UI DataGrid, e.g. https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/filtering/

But I don't see the possiblity to make a list with text to filter. So one row contains "start", "stop" and "undefined" as values. How can I filter them directly without typing in the text all the time? (something like a list of predefined values)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You have to implement your own `FilterPanel`, which you pass to the data grid via `components` prop. [`components` prop exposes overridable components](https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/#slots) within the data grid. You can use it like this:

```js
<DataGrid
  {...data}
  components={{
    FilterPanel: YourFilterPanel
  }}
/>
```

You can also override the props passed to these overridden components via `componentProps` prop in the same manner.

[See the default `GridFilterPanel` from the library for inspiration](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/blob/fa346f0fbe3d9b9eea9bb403fe4675f544d6abf9/packages/grid/_modules_/grid/components/panel/filterPanel/GridFilterPanel.tsx).

Comment: Btw I'm considering I'll implement the filtering on my own -> completely bypassing the API Data Grid provides

Answer (score 2):

I think the singleSelect data type will meet your needs. https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#special-properties

In your column definition you would add:

```
type: 'singleSelect',
valueOptions: ['start', 'stop', 'undefined']
```

This will give you a dropdown in your filter where you can select those values instead of typing them into an input field.